# Proteus Simulation Error With 555 and HCSR04

Tags: simulation, design, 555, proteus, hc-sr04

[image: Circuit Diagram]
Hello internet, I stuck at some point while simulating my circuit. This is a circuit that will measure distance and display it on seven segment displays. Firstly, When I tried to simulate this circuit I'm getting these errors;

> [SPICE] Gmin step [0 of 120] failed: GMIN=0.001

> [SPICE] Gmin stepping failed.

> [SPICE] Source step [0 of 120] failed: source factor =   0.0000

> [SPICE] Too many iterations without convergence.

> Real Time Simulation failed to start.

When I connect an oscilloscope to the 3rd pin of the 555 (U3), the simulation works, but this time I can't get the result I want. I tried to simulate only 555 circuits in another project and they can produce their outputs correctly. I tried to simulate only HCSR04 but I couldn't see anything on the echo pin. Did I make any mistake while connecting some components? Is there a way to simulate the whole circuit?

Comment: Does the HCSR04 even have a simulation model?

Comment: yes, it has simulation model

Comment: What does Proteus manual says about how to use HCSR04 in a simulation?

Comment: I don't know, where should I look for the manual?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem about the HCSR04. When I change battery with power pin and remove the resistor at the seven segments upper pins, it is solved but I can't simulate in real time. I'm getting CPU error.